# OpenGL glfwCreateWindow returning null upon execution

Tags: c++

When i run this code glfwCreateWindow returns null and prints "Failed to open GLFW window", but I'm not sure why its not working. I've already tried with OpenGL 2.1, and it gave the same error.

```
/*  1 */ #include <stdio.h>
/*  2 */ #include <stdlib.h>
/*  3 */ 
/*  4 */ #include <GL/glew.h>
/*  5 */ #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
/*  6 */ 
/*  7 */ 
/*  8 */ int main()
/*  9 */ {
/* 10 */     glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
/* 11 */     glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
/* 12 */     glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
/* 13 */     glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
/* 14 */     glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
/* 15 */ 
/* 16 */     
/* 17 */     GLFWwindow* window;
/* 18 */     window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Test", NULL, NULL);
/* 19 */     if (window == NULL)
/* 20 */     {
/* 21 */         fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window\n");
/* 22 */         glfwTerminate();
/* 23 */         return -1;
/* 24 */     }
/* 25 */     glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
/* 26 */     glewExperimental=true;
/* 27 */     if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
/* 28 */     {
/* 29 */         fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialise GLEW\n");
/* 30 */         return -1;
/* 31 */     }
/* 32 */     return 0;
/* 33 */ }
```

Comment: You need to call [`glfwInit`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/quick.html#quick_init_term) before creating a context.

Comment: Also please don't number the code lines. It makes it harder for us to run it ourselves.

Comment: I fixed your line number issue @HolyBlackCat was complaining about... ;-)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Apologies, I just copied the code from vim and i use nu